# queue of array elements in java

Tags: java, queue

i am a beginner in java and i have an exercise for homework!i want to find the shortest path in a map! i will do the bfs algorithm! i read the map and i put the chars in a array!After that i want to do bfs in the array so i want to make a queue of elements with two fields, for example a queue that every element is an array [2], in order to put in the first field the array position of the element and in the other one the cost to get there!Any ideas how to do this??Thank you a lot for your time and your help!
i tried this but it didn't work!

```
    Queue  <int []> queue = new LinkedList <int []> ();
    int [] start = {thesi,0};
```

Comment: What are `thesi` and `start`!

Comment: thesi is the first element of the array in which i want to save the position!

Comment: start is the first element of the queue!

Comment: Please improve your post by fixing the formatting and a proper code snippet.

Comment: i just want to make a queue that contains an array but i don't knw how to do this in java!

Comment: Your snippet works. What kind of problem you have with it?

Comment: Queue  <int []> queue = new LinkedList <int []> (); gives me a compiler error! it writes "Queue and Linkedlist cannot be reslved to a type"

Comment: You must import this classes. Use "import" statement before class declaration.

Comment: thank's a lot!but it is my first day writing java so please tell me how to import the classes!i don't know what is import!thank you again!

Comment: @ΗλίαςΠαλαιολόγος  if you're using an IDE, you can hover over the class underlined in red and the IDE can automatically import it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import java.util.Queue and java.util.LinkedList, the same way you did with java.io.File. See this link for [more information](http://beginwithjava.blogspot.com.br/2008/06/import-statements.html).

```
 import java.util.Queue;
 import java.util.LinkedList;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

 import java.util.Scanner; 

 public class ask1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // your code...
    }
 }
```